# How do I make an abr file out of multiple gbr files using GIMP?

Tags: gimp, brush

I made several brushes (gbr files) in GIMP and I'd like to combine them into a set, how do I make an abr file?
I'm using GIMP 2.10.24

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can't export an ABR brush set from GIMP.  Although GIMP can use ABR brushes (to a degree), these are an Adobe format, not native to GIMP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if you want to formulate it as such I'd accept it as the answer